# changing the initialization order of the unit in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm using Delphi XE7 for developing windows 32 bit application.

My application contains many units, which has an initialization section. I need to initialize one particular initialization section at first.

Is it possible to set the priority?
I have tried to write the initialization section in dpr file, but the compiler has rejected this.

Please help me to execute the particular initialization section at first. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have no control over prioritizing `initialization` sections. The only thing you can do is reorder the units in your `uses` clauses. Make sure the unit for the "one particular initialization section" is earlier in the `uses` list than other units, or is the first unit in the `dpr` file.

Comment: Have you tried putting the unit first in the .Dpr file?  And, what Remy says.

Comment: It can often be hard to control this, you may to consider solutions that don't rely on initialization order.

Comment: I ended up adding one unit IntializeFILF, it has two methods AssureFI and AddtoLF.  AssureFI initializes stuff like Log files and Tracing Units. All other initialization code first calls that and optionally adds its finalization to AssureLF, no further issues since then..

Answer (score 16):

In simple terms, initialization sections are executed in the order in which the units are introduced in any `uses` clauses.  But it is a little more complicated than that due to the fact that initialization of a unit is performed only *after the initialization of any units that that unit itself references* (where they have not already been initialized).

i.e. Given:

```
program Foo;

  uses
    Unit1,
    Unit2,
    Unit3;
```

---

```
unit Unit1;

interface

  uses
    Unit3;
```

Then the unit initialization order will be:

```
Unit3
Unit1
Unit2
```

This is because `Unit1` introduces `Unit3`, so even though `Unit1` is listed first in the **dpr** uses, `Unit3` is in fact initialized first, followed by the initialization of `Unit1`.

If you remember that the `initialization` section occurs *after* any `uses` clauses in a unit, it does make sense.

Therefore the only way to be absolutely sure of any one unit being initialized before *any* other is to list it first in the **DPR** `uses` clause and for that unit to take no dependencies on any other units (except where those units are not dependent on, or otherwise interfere with, the initialization being performed) .

It need not necessarily be *strictly* first of course.  e.g. if you are using a replacement memory manager (such as FastMM) then this will absolutely need to be the very first unit listed in your **dpr** `uses` clause.  You simply need to make sure that the unit you need to be initialised before any other (of your units) is then listed before any other unit which might bring your other units in:

```
program  Foo;

uses
  FastMM,            // MUST be first but won't bring any of 'my' units in, so this is OK

  SysUtils,          // These too are fine coming next because again they don't
  Forms,             // reference 'my' units

  MyInitUnit,        // <- This is where it is important to list 'my' guaranteed first/earliest
                     //     initialisated unit of all 'my' units

  MyFirstAppUnit,    // And now the rest ...
  etc;
```

Of course, if the unit that you wish to initialise first **does** need to be initialised before *any* other, including RTL units (in the same way that FastMM etc need to be) then you would need to reflect that in the **dpr** `uses` list by declaring your unit earlier still.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Delphi documentation is misleading.  From my own research I have discovered that units are not always initialised in the order in which they are referenced in uses clauses.  If you're not interested in what I have found skip the next paragraph.

> Using the utility ProcMon from SysInternals and monitoring the process
> of building Delphi code I can see when unit files are opened, and when
> DCU files are written.  It seems that the unit files are opened in the
> order in which they are referenced in uses clauses, but the compiled
> DCUs may be written in a different order.  By putting breakpoints into
> the **initialization** section of units I have confirmed that they are
> called in the order in which the DCUs are written to disk, not the
> order in which the units are referenced.  For simple cases the two
> orders can be equivalent, but it's definitely not true that the
> initialization code is always called in the order in which units are
> referred to in unit clauses.

**How to force an initialisation order**

The approach I have adopted when units needs to be initialised in a particular order is to have a public method in each unit that needs initialising.  This method is called in the `initialization` section.

For each unit there is a unit level (private) variable that indicates whether the initialization has been run or not.  (For simple cases a boolean is good enough, for more complex cases you may be creating an initialisation object and you can use a pointer to that).  Then in each module you check if you have been initialised, if not you call the initialisation in all of the other units you need to have initialised before you, and then do your own initialisation.

So, in the case where you are using a simple boolean you might have:

```
unit InitFirst;

interface

uses Classes;

procedure _DoInitialisation();

implementation

var
  _blInitialised: Boolean;

  procedure _DoInitialisation();
  begin
    if(not _blInitialised) then
    begin
      // initialisation code goes here
      _blInitialised:=True;
    end;
  end;

initialization

  _DoInitialisation();

end.
```

and

```
unit InitSecond;

interface

uses Classes;

procedure _DoInitialisation();

implementation

uses  InitFirst;

var
  _blInitialised: Boolean;

  procedure _DoInitialisation();
  begin
    if(not _blInitialised) then
    begin
      InitFirst._DoInitialisation();
      // initialisation code goes here
      _blInitialised:=True;
    end;
  end;

initialization

  _DoInitialisation();

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialization sections are executed in the order that the units appear in the `uses` clause.

So, you may force your unit to initialize first by moving it up in the `uses` list.

Comment: Not necessarily in that order. See Deltics' answer.

Comment: What about units in the interface `uses` list v. the one in the implementation one?

Comment: I think it works like this: all units are listed in "order of appearance", with duplicates removed. Then each unit on which others depend is listed before the first one that depends on it. This is checked for all units. The resulting list is the order of initialization.